# How to access a method as a member variable

Tags: php

I have a class, `Place`, with a function named `thing()`. I'd like to be able to access the method as a variable, something like `$dc=new Place; echo $dc->thing;`. How can I do that without creating a member variable?

Comment: Create a public static function thing() and then call that using class name `place::thing();`

Comment: `$func ='thing'; echo $dc->$func();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I was looking for! 
I would need to overload [PHP's `__get()` function.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get)